# How to access javascript varibale which is set in jquery block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've problem in javascript function, there are two variables which are declared in global scope of function and set within jquery plugin. How can i get these variable value out side of jquery.

```
 function GetDirectionFromCurrentLocation(StoreAddress) {
var positionStore = null;
var positionCurrent = null;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': StoreAddress }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        positionStore = results[0].geometry.location;
    }
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            positionCurrent = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        });
    }

});
window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + positionCurrent + "&daddr=" + positionStore + "&hl=en&output=html");
 }
```

These variables are always null.

Comment: If you want those variables accessible outside of that function, you must declare them outside of that function.

Comment: these vars are always null because geocode is an asynchrounous function. You should insert window.open inside callback (after second `if`)

Comment: conlose.log those variables after the second if condition. And check there values.

Comment: @PatrickD i diclared these variables outside of function but still these are null.

Comment: @chumkiu with in if condtion its working fine but window is open in popup, i have use all '_blank', '_newTab' etc. i need to open this in new tab. is there any way to open in new tab by using windows.open in if condition

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your geocode call is asynchronous and when your code reaches the window open call, the background job isn't finished.

```
function GetDirectionFromCurrentLocation(StoreAddress) {
    var positionStore = null;
    var positionCurrent = null;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': StoreAddress }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            positionStore = results[0].geometry.location;
        }
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                positionCurrent = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            });
        }

        if (positionCurrent && positionStore) {
            window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + positionCurrent + "&daddr=" + positionStore + "&hl=en&output=html");
        }
    });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `window.open` call inside of the anonymous function. Your variables are null because your `window.open` line of code is being called BEFORE the anonymous function is being called.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the open the new window inside the jQuery function, as it's need to be synchronous to get the proper values.

Comment: inside jquery its open the window in popup. i need to open window in new tab.